# Elastic Search: Get Exact Match first the other match

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elastic Search we have function: setDefaultOperator.

```
$query->setDefaultOperator('AND')->setFields(array('keyword'));
```

Above gives only exact match.

```
$query->setDefaultOperator('OR')->setFields(array('keyword'));
```

Above gives all matches.(But not exact match first)

I need exact match first then other match. Any idea?

I am using Elastic Search for the first time. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to do it using query_string 
then you have to define the default operator in order to change the default one which is OR.

> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

have a look full example below using Kibana

```
PUT /phone/brand/1
{
  "color" : "black",
  "name" : "Samsung"
}

PUT /phone/brand/2
{
  "color" : "black",
  "name" : "Iphone"
}

PUT /phone/brand/3
{
  "color" : "white",
  "name" : "Samsung"
}

//query string 
GET /phone/brand/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": ["color","name"], 
      "default_operator": "AND", 
      "query": "Samsung black"
    }
  }
}
```